# CSS error on a custom mobile menu for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I have an error in a custom mobile menu for Wordpress TwentyThirteen theme.

The website is this: http://nhgunshow.com/

The mobile menu doesn't work and it looks like a CSS problem, but I haven't been able to figure it out for the past 2 days. Something keeps the menu from showing when the button is clicked, but I can't understand what is wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that your hiding the `ul` thats in the navbar

```
@media (max-width: 643px)
ul.nav-menu, div.nav-menu > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

remove that code and it should work.

Comment: Awesome, man. I am such a dork when it comes to CSS. Thank you!